# issues with the usage of UDID

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i heard that apple is rejecting the apps which are using UDID, for Push Notifications purpose i used deviceToken.

i think UDID and deviceToken both are different, so using of deviceToken may not cause any issues.

can anyone please give me the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UDID and the device token you get from push are **completely separate things**. As long as you're not using `UIDevice`'s `uniqueIdentifier` property, you're absolutely fine.

Comment: It's deprecated and Apple are reportedly actively rejecting apps that use it. Hence this question.

Comment: You also should make sure that no 3rd party libs are accessing the UDID - even if you do not invoke that call indirectly. Phonegap 1.5 has such a call and if the review team just scans for that like the usage of private APIs, it could lead to a reject.

Answer (score 1):

No, the device token used for push notifications is different to the UDID. You will not have to change anything for push.

Answer (score 0):

Device token and UDID is completely different. You can very well use device token.